# Help understanding exponential in Feynman-Kac proof

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, heat-equation, semigroup-of-operators, functional-calculus

I am working through the proof of the Feynman-Kac formula in Johnson and Lapidus' book *The Feynman Integral and Feynman's Operational Calculus.* In one of the steps of the proof they write that $$e^{-t(H_0 + V + ||V||_\infty)} = e^{-t||V||_\infty} e^{-t(H_0 + V)}$$ where $e^{-t(H_0 + V)}$ is the heat semigroup with generator $-(H_0 + V) = \frac 1 2 \Delta - V$. The $L^\infty$ norm $||V||_\infty$ is just a constant, but I am confused as to why we are allowed to pull it out of the exponent. The operator $H_0 + V$ is not a bounded operator so it doesn't seem like we can use the standard result that $e^Ae^B = e^{A+B}$ where $A$ and $B$ are bounded and commute.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A constant commutes with everything, so perhaps that's the reason.

Comment: Yes but $e^{-t(H_0 + V)}$ doesn't have a power series representation so I'm not sure how that helps? Does it follow perhaps from the fact that we can define $e^{-t(H_0 + V)}$ by a functional calculus using spectral theory so that it has all the normal properties of the exponential function?

Comment: Are you familiar with the spectral theory for unbounded self-adjoint operators or analytic semi-groups at all?  As you suggest, this must be an exercise in manipulating such functional calculi/semi-groups.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only know very little about it. Do you know of a good reference perhaps that might help me figure out how to justify the separation of the exponential? Thank you so much.

Comment: I think actually it's just a really simple case of the Trotter product where you use the fact that $e^-t||V||_\infty$ commutes with everything since it is a constant.

Comment: @a7b You can use the Trotter formula, but this would be massive overkill. Which definition of $e^{-tA}$ for unbounded $A$ do you know?